# Is it possible to transform a propositional logic formula so that every propositions appear only once?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm trying to compare two formulae to see which one is easier to satisfy and I thought that comparing how many models they have would be a good way to do so.

From what I've seen and read, it seems harder to count the number of models when a proposition appear more than once in a formula so I was wondering if it is possible to transform any propositional logic formula so that every propositions in it appears only once. If it is, is it more optimal to count the number of models after doing this transformation ?

Comment: That seems to depend on which connectives you have. If it's only the usual $\{{\neg},{\land},{\lor},{\to}\}$, then I don't think the "exclusive or" of $A$ and $B$ can be expressed without repeating a letter.

Comment: You're right thanks for the answer.

Comment: With the standard connectives $\neg,\land,\lor$ the answer is negative. The problem of minimizing the number of occurrences is known as fanout minimization, and there are known algorithms for it, see [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18474607). But if the goal is satisfiability, it is trivially determined when the formula is in the disjunctive normal form, and one can always put a formula into that, see [Unrestricted Satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Unrestricted_satisfiability_(SAT)).

Comment: @Conifold: I wouldn't use "trivially determined" about one of the most well-known NP-complete problems ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm "SAT is trivial if the formulas are restricted to those in disjunctive normal form... But it can take exponential time and space to convert a general SAT problem to disjunctive normal form".

Comment: @Conifold: Whoops, missed that you were talking about DNF. But_counting_ satisfying assignments seems to be as hard in DNF as it is for CNF, due to duality.

Answer (score 1):

There is no finite set of truth functions that will allow you to write *every* propositional formula without repeating letters.

Suppose that you have $k$ functions in your set.

Without loss of generality we can assume that there is no *unary* function -- you can avoid that by instead having each of your functions come in versions that precompose it with $\neg$ in each position, as well as with the everywhere true and false functions. Then there are still only finitely many functions.

Now if you have an expression with involving $n$ propositional variables, then without repeating variables there are at most $n-1$ function applications in the expression. So the *number of symbols* if we write down the expression in Polish notation is at most $2n-1$, and there are $n+k$ different symbols, so the number of different expressions is *at most* $(n+k)^{2n-1}$.

On the other hand, the number of truth functions we might want to express is $2^{2^n}$, which grows much faster than the number of expressions. So there cannot be an expression for each truth function.